# Applescript — can't find bundled resource

Tags: scripting, applescript, photoshop, batch-processing, photoshop-script

I'm trying to write an Applescript droplet for Photoshop that resizes and watermarks multiple photos. I want to bundle the watermark images and save as an app so I can distribute it within my organization, but I can't seem to get the script to see the bundled resource.

I dragged my "watermark.png" image to the "Bundle Contents" sidebar, and am using the following file processing statements:

```
on process_item(this_item)
    set myPath to alias this_item as text
    tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS5.1"
        open file myPath
        set thisDocument to current document
        set ruler units of settings to pixel units
        resize image thisDocument width 640
        set wmPath to path to resource "watermark.png"
        open file wmPath
    end tell
end process_item
```

but I always get the following error:

```
Resource not found.
```

Do I have to do something special to make sure the script can find the bundled resources?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are asking the application "Photoshop" to find the resource. It does not know how to do this.

To fix this, either move the line `set wmPath to path to resource "watermark.png"` outside of the block `tell application` (for example, before the line `tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS5.1"`),
or change it to:

```
tell me to set wmPath to path to resource "watermark.png"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also had some luck with    "set myFile to (path to resource "watermark.png" in bundle path to me) as text"